# Mac OS X Force Internet Sharing Traffic Through Proxy

Tags: macos, networking, proxy

I have Internet Sharing set up on my Mac OS 10.9.5 machine, sharing my Ethernet connection to any devices connected to the created Wi-Fi hotspot. I'm looking for a way to force all that traffic through a proxy server so I can monitor the traffic using Charles.

[image: Proxy Settings]

I had assumed that, since Charles automatically sets up proxy settings (above) on the outgoing Ethernet connection that all the Wi-Fi traffic would already be proxied, but I was wrong. It seems Internet Sharing creates a new bridge (named "bridge100" at the moment) that does not run through the same network service even though the packets go out the same network interface.

I can see all the traffic generated by my machine in Charles, just not the traffic from other machines. Is there a way to set up the routing so my proxy settings for the Ethernet are also applied to the bridge? If not, is there any way to route the bridge's traffic to the same proxy?

Comment: On Linux, a so-called “Transparent Proxy” can be realized with `iptables`, [like this](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-5.html). I’m not familiar with OS X’ firewall, but this is basically what you’ll have to replicate.

Answer (score 1):

I expect this is not going to be simple, if possible.

When you have a proxy server, either running on the machine itself, or on a device on the network, the client apps (e.g. whatever is going out to the inet) needs to direct its traffic to the proxy server (not just directly to the relevant network interface). This is configured either in the client app settings or at the OS level. However, when you set up a proxy at the OS level, as you show in your screen shot, that is probably set for the user session, and may not affect daemons (not sure).

The hotspot is probably running at a daemon level, and may not respect that proxy setting.

It might make sense to think of the problem differently. E.g. perhaps run ethereal or other packet sniffer, and look at the traffic hitting the ethernet port (which would include traffic to/from the OSX-based hotspot). (A packet sniffer is lower level than Charles, but that may be the price of getting lower level access to traffic.)

Comment: To add to Mr.Jones comment, Proxy servers *generally* proxy specific protocols. In the case of Charles it's HTTP and HTTPS traffic. Charles (at least according to the web site) was built for debugging, not general purpose proxying. It can probably do that, but squid is probably a sounder choice. 

Also, it's not YOUR mac you need to configure. It's your clients .

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into OpenDNS? You would replace your DNS IPs on your router with their IPs and then you will be able to view a log of traffic on your network. You would do this by logging into your account on opendns.com.

You can also deny traffic to certain domains. There is a "Personal" free plan option.

Answer (score 0):

You ever wonder how Charles Proxy gets all of the HTTP/HTTPS traffic on the box?  I probably should research this more, but I suspect that it sets itself up as the system proxy.  Any client that respects the outbound proxy configured on the OS will use the outbound proxy and be visible to Charles.  However there are those that do not - for instance `curl` doesn't get caught by Charles (unless you somehow tell curl to use a proxy, such as --proxy or -x or setting http_proxy, etc.).

And so, with a non-transparent proxy like Charles, you'll have to rely on client behavior.

Fortunately, a lot of applications do respect the outbound proxy set at the system level (and many applications also allow you to specify an application configuration as well).  And so, by setting the outbound proxy system proxy, you can get a lot of your applications (certainly browsers) to go through Charles.

If you have admin access to the hosts using Internet Sharing on your network you might as well set the client's system outbound proxy to point to your Charles proxy.

And one more thing - when I performed this configuration, Charles Proxy wanted me to manually Accept the connection.  Charles is ok with connections made to localhost, but when the client is coming from another box, you have to manually Accept the connection.  Charles only prompted me once per host.

Another thought on this: there are network mechanisms for setting the outbound proxy on your client computers.  Systems can learn the outbound proxy from their DHCP query (when they ask the network for their dynamically assigned IP address).  Does MACOS allow you to specify the outbound proxy when doing internet connection sharing?  I don't know, that's how I found your post.  I am currently looking for a way to configure Internet Connection Sharing to also provide clients with the outbound proxy.

However, if your internet sharing doesn't allow you to specify the outbound proxy, it's probably not worth pursuing the automatic approach and stick with manual configuration on each sharing client.

Even more obscure than the DHCP approach is the WPAD approach.  WPAD, or Web Proxy Auto-Discovery, is a technology that allows browsers to discover the outbound proxy (a bit of an over simplification because it actually can supply conditional logic for finding multiple  outbound proxies).  WPAD is probably only for web browsers (but I suppose any client that is javascript capable may use it).  There is a lot to read about WPAD,  but unless you have control over DNS in your system it's probably not a  viable solution for you.

As long as I am going off topic, I have an associate who ran raspberry pi with the equivalent of internet connection sharing on it.  The pi device was also running bind (a DNS server) and  dns-masq so that it could intercept some of the DNS queries and return its own IP address.  And lastly, it was running an HTTP(S) proxy.  So the clients would unknowingly send the proxy requests that would then be proxied on their behalf to the intended URLs.  And that's how my colleague avoided having to set up outbound proxies on the clients.

Answer (score -1):

Your question summary (force traffic sharing through proxy) does not match your intended purpose, which is to monitor traffic. And the screenshot you're showing is doing something entirely different yet.

To monitor traffic, you do not need to setup a proxy. Once you have forced all the other devices to route all their traffic through your machine, all you need to add to the mix is [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) (running on your bridge) and you will get access to the traffic.

If you really do want to setup a proxy, have all the traffic be routed through it and have that logged, what you're looking for is called a [transparent forward proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy).

The screenshot you're sharing is what you would configure if you wanted to setup a proxy for all the traffic originating from your machine. Which is what 'Charles' is showing you.

Comment: 1) Wireshark is a passive monitoring tool. It lacks some very very important features that tools like Charles Proxy include. 

2) Charles is not able to monitor traffic on bridge100, which for some use cases is absolutely necessary. 

The question summary perfectly matches the intended purpose. It was you who didn't understand the problem at hand.